# Auto-size TextView with API before 26

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to auto-size my TextView to fit in a specific width on one line, it was quite easy for API 26 and above, however, I want to support my app for use with APIs back to Lolipop. I am having a hard time trying to do this with java code. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Auto-size textview was added in API 26.

Comment: Exactly - I need to auto-size and support APIs before 26.

Comment: the cue here is *added in API 26*, as in it doesn't exist in earlier versions of Android

Comment: But what I want to do is do the same thing - alternatively for lower APIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the support library for older APIs
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can !

replace

```
android:autoSizeTextTyp="uniform"
```

with :

```
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

(At least working on sdk 23, with a simple TextView)

Comment: Also, you have to use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView instead of TextView

Comment: What is the androidx dependency for this support library?

Answer (score 1):

May be it 'll work for you. This is the Library,

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview